# Dynamics CRM Javascript to Prevent saving entity if note is not saved

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In Dynamics CRM 2013 when you create a note inside a specific entity and without clicking "DONE" on the note form or without clicking anywhere else on the entity but clicking directly on the "save and close" button, the note is not saved.

For the note to be saved you should click the done button or click anywhere outside and only then click the "save and close" button.

95% of the time this is ok but there are multiple times when users forget to do this and the notes are lost.

This same problem has also been asked here years ago without any reply or solution: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/163853

I was trying to show a message or prevent the save function of the lead entity if there is a note that has not been saved but I do not know how to access that notes form through javascript and how to check if there is an open note that is not saved, which would prevent saving the lead at all.

Anyone that can help?

Comment: See if Nicknow response is helpful in your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136696/remove-notes-autosave-functionality-by-adding-other-entitys-notes-on-form-in-c

Comment: Training users is always better than coding. Especially when coding means to introduce potential bugs.